# SQL Query to get top rows until ColName = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am storing a list of Messages in my database (so that if I crash I will not lose them).

But when I pull them out, I need to pull them out in chunks and in order.

What I am looking for is a query that will give me the top x rows until column `IsWeirdMessage` = 1.

So, assuming I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyMessages(MessageId bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
    MyMessage varchar(100), IsWeirdMessage bit)

INSERT INTO MyMessages(MyMessage, IsWeirdMessage)
SELECT 'SomeValue1', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue2', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue3', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue3', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue4', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue5', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'WeirdThingHere', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue7', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue8', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue9', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'OtherWeirdStuff', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeValue11', 0  
GO
```

How could I craft a query that will get me *SomeValue1* through *SomeValue5* (in order), keying off of `IsWeirdMessage`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
select * from MyMessages
where messageid > @MessageID
and messageid <=
  (select min(messageid) from MyMessages
   where IsWeirdMessage = 1 and messageid > @MessageID)
order by messageid
```

Where the @MessageID is the value of the last weird message you retrieved.  You would start with 0 to get the first batch, then 7 to get the second batch, etc.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10336/9

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Also thanks for showing me SQLFiddle.  That is very nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.MessageID, m.MyMessage
FROM dbo.MyMessages AS m
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MyMessages AS m2
  WHERE IsWeirdMessage = 1 
  AND m2.MessageID < m.MessageID
)
ORDER BY MessageID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I went with Mellamokb's solution because it ended up doing index seeks in my actual tables.  Your solution was great, but it was doing index scans.

Comment: To be fair, you didn't tell us your index structure. Did the queries perform differently, or did you just see a scan and assume it was worse? Often a range scan is hiding behind what looks like an index seek.

Comment: True, I did not.  (I did not think it would matter)  Both answers were very good (and really performed well).  I had to find something (however very small) to pick one over the other...  As for Range Scans behind Index Seeks... That makes me nervous.  I have never heard of that.  But the actual performance (time to run) of both was close enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.*
from
    (   select
            row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as PartitionId
            ,isnull((select max(t.MessageId) from MyMessages t where t.MessageId < tb.MessageId and t.IsWeirdMessage = 1), 0) as StartID
            ,tb.MessageId as EndId
        from MyMessages tb
        where IsWeirdMessage = 1
        union all
        select count(case when IsWeirdMessage = 1 then MessageId else null end) + 1
            ,max(case when IsWeirdMessage = 1 then MessageId else 0 end)
            ,max(messageId) + 1
        from MyMessages
    ) as a
    cross apply 
    (   select * from MyMessages b
        where
            b.MessageId > a.StartID
            and b.MessageId < a.EndID
    ) as b
where a.PartitionId = @PartID
```

where the @PartID is identifier of Partition that you want to choose